# bootstrap 4 carousel control position

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rcqs79t/1/). How can I remove the `absolute position` of left and right icon to have the following structure?

The carousel item should be in the middle.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2rcqs79t/1/)

[image]

Comment: could you explain it a litte bit more? Why the arrows are in the other side?

Comment: @bep42, i am just trying to remove the `absolute` arrows to make it `relative`